# Fetch All Record Types from CloudKit?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

Is there a way to fetch all record types from CloudKit? I can only find a way to fetch records for 1 specific record type.

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: String, predicate: NSPredicate) 
CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.perform(query: CKQuery, inZoneWith: CKRecordZoneID?, completionHandler: ([CKRecord]?, Error?) -> Void)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808865/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-recordtypes-in-a-database

Comment: @rmaddy I was hoping I wouldn't need to make a record type to keep track of my record types... thanks haha

Comment: If you have all the CKRecordID you can use it in the CKFetchRecordsOperation

Comment: Not sure, but you can always just set up a few different factions for each recordType and load them separately (yet at the same time)